# ListAdapter within a fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a List of some entries, resulting a query on a php server. I'm using a Fragment, which calls an `AsyncTask` class named `DescarregarLlistatEntrades`. This class, basically parses json data from a php execution, then I want to populate a List, but as `DescarregarLlistatEntrades` isnt extending `ListActivity`, I can't use method `setListAdapter`.

Here's the code:

The fragment:

```
public class MyFragmentB extends Fragment {
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> llistatEntrades;
Context cont=getActivity(); //Recupero el contexte per poder pasar-lo.

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.llistat_fotos, container, false);

    //hashmap per al llistat de les entrades que hi han al servidor
    llistatEntrades=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //descarrego totes les imatges en segon plà i omplo el view
    new DescarregarLlistatEntrades(cont, myFragmentView, llistatEntrades).execute();

    //Recupero el el layout de la view per poder fer coses am ella a posteriori.
    ListView lv = (ListView)myFragmentView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    return myFragmentView;
}
```

DescarregarLlistatEntrades:

```
public class DescarregarLlistatEntrades extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
private Context mContext;
private View rootView;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> llistatEntrades;
private String linkFoto, dataUpload, usuariUpload, comentariUpload;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private String url_get_entrades = "http://192.168.1.33/testing/recuperaentrades.php"; //passantli per get el id de la setmana 

public DescarregarLlistatEntrades(Context context, View rootView, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> llistatEntrades){
    this.mContext=context;
    this.rootView=rootView;
    this.llistatEntrades=llistatEntrades;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    [...]
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) { 
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("setmana", "1"));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_entrades, "GET", params);
    JSONArray entradesObj;
    try {
        int success = json.getInt("success");
        //mirem si hi ha success
        if (success==1){
            entradesObj = json.getJSONArray("entrades"); //recupero totes les entrades
            for (int i=0; i<entradesObj.length();i++){
                JSONObject entrada = entradesObj.getJSONObject(i); //recupero cada objecte
                //guardo cada camp de cada entrada a variables:
                this.usuariUpload=entrada.getString("usuariUploader");
                this.linkFoto=entrada.getString("urlFoto");
                this.comentariUpload=entrada.getString("comentariUsuari");
                this.dataUpload=entrada.getString("dataUpload");
                //creo el hashmap dels valors anteriors
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("usuariUpload", this.usuariUpload);
                map.put("linkFoto", this.linkFoto);
                map.put("comentariUpload", this.comentariUpload);
                map.put("dataUpload", this.dataUpload);
                this.llistatEntrades.add(map);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("debugging","No hi han entrades..");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    this.pDialog.dismiss(); //amago el dialog
    // updating UI
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this.mContext, this.llistatEntrades,
            R.layout.entrada_llista, new String[] { "usuariUpload",
                    "linkFoto","comentariUpload", "dataUpload"},
            new int[] { R.id.userNameUploader, R.id.titolFoto, R.id.comment, R.id.hora });
    // updating listview
    setListAdapter(adapter); //THIS LINE!!

}
```

> "The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type
>   DescarregarLlistatEntrades"

Should I use another method when using fragments?

Note that I pass to the AsyncTask class, the Context and the Inflater. Maybe I've to pass something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass instance of `ListView` to asynctask so when it sets list adapter to this instance of `ListView`. If you use ordinary `Fragment` - you can add `ListView` to layout, retrieve it in `onCreateView` method and pass to async task. Also you can use `ListFragment` this way you can get `ListView` by using `getViewMethod` in fragment.  Or just get list view from `rootView` if it's the root of fragment layout. Something like:

```
((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view)).setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Finally I used first option. Passed the instance of the ListView to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Final code:
This is the AsyncTask Class:

```
public DescarregarLlistatEntrades(Context context, View rootView, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> llistatEntrades, ListView lv){
    this.mContext=context;
    this.rootView=rootView;
    this.llistatEntrades=llistatEntrades;
    this.lv=lv;
}
```

And the fragment

```
public class MyFragmentB extends Fragment {
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> llistatEntrades;
Context cont;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.cont=getActivity(); //Recupero el contexte per poder pasar-lo.
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.llistat_fotos, container, false);

    //hashmap per al llistat de les entrades que hi han al servidor
    llistatEntrades=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //Recupero el el layout de la view per poder fer coses am ella a posteriori.
    ListView lv = (ListView)myFragmentView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //descarrego totes les imatges en segon plà i omplo el view
    new DescarregarLlistatEntrades(cont, myFragmentView, llistatEntrades, lv).execute();

    return myFragmentView;
}
```

Working like charm!!